# Is it possible to determine verify the client_id with an access_token

Tags: google-oauth

Is it possible to determine the originating client_id of an access_token by calling a google api with the access_token?

Answer (score 1):

There's no documented API for introspecting access tokens, but there is the tokeninfo endpoint:

curl https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=

I wouldn’t be too eager to put an https round trip in a production workflow, though.